# How to convert list of pair tuples in dataframe into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column where each cells data looks like:

`[('a', '2000'),('b', '4000'),('d', '5000')]`.

Some would have 4 pairs with c. How can I convert all of them into new columns filling 
`df['a'] , df['b'] , df['c'] , df['d']`  ?

Comment: From your expected result it seems that you need to use Pandas. Could you tell us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't vectorisable. One efficient solution would be to feed a list of dictionaries to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor via `list` + `map` with `dict`:

```
s = pd.Series([[('a', '2000'),('b', '4000'),('d', '5000')],
               [('a', '1000'),('b', '3000'),('c', '6000'),('d', '7000')]])

# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['data'])

# convert list of tuples to dict for each element in series
res = pd.DataFrame(list(map(dict, df['data'])))

print(res)

      a     b     c     d
0  2000  4000   NaN  5000
1  1000  3000  6000  7000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
d=[('a', '2000'),('b', '4000'),('d', '5000')]  
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).T   
df.columns = df.iloc[0]    
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it :

```
l = [('a', '2000'),('b', '4000'),('d', '5000')]
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(l)])
```

If your data is like nested list of tuples then try like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(dict, l)))
```

Output will be like :

```
      a     b     d
0  2000  4000  5000
```